# jQuery - passing value from one input to another

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a form, with several input fields that are `title`, `name`, `address` etc

What I want to do, is to get these values and 'put them' into values of other input fields. For example

```
<label for="first_name">First Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name" />

<label for="surname">Surname</label>
<input type="text" name="surname" />

<label for="firstname">Firstname</label>
<input type="text" name="firstname" disabled="disabled" />
```

So If I enter `John` in the `first_name` field, then the value of `firstname` will also be `John`.

Many thanks

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Assuming you can put ID's on the inputs:

```
$('#name').change(function() {
    $('#firstname').val($(this).val());
});
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/SDHNY/)

Otherwise you'll have to select using the names:

```
$('input[name="name"]').change(function() {
    $('input[name="firstname"]').val($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: You can also use the name attribute. You just have to write some more characters. $(":input[name='name']") and so far.

Comment: I used id of the input fields and worked really well, thanks.

Comment: Perfect. I did it both ways so if you edit the second it also updates the first. (You just use the same function but reverse the `ID`s. Also I did it on `keyup`. That just makes a wee bit more funky as they update in real time :-)

Comment: If I want to take from input1 of form one and then take this value and set it to input 2 of form 2 ? How is that done then ?

Answer (score 7):

It's simpler if you modify your HTML a little bit:

```
<label for="first_name">First Name</label>
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" />

<label for="surname">Surname</label>
<input type="text" id="surname" name="surname" />

<label for="firstname">Firstname</label>
<input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" disabled="disabled" />
```

then it's relatively simple

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#name').change(function() {
      $('#firstname').val($('#name').val());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Get input1 data to send them to input2 immediately

```
<div>
<label>Input1</label>
 <input type="text" id="input1" value="">
</div>

</br>
<label>Input2</label>
<input type="text" id="input2" value="">

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#input1").keyup(function () {
                var value = $(this).val();
                $("#input2").val(value);
            });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score 1):

Add ID attributes with same values as name attributes and then you can do this:

```
$('#first_name').change(function () {
  $('#firstname').val($(this).val());
});
```