# How to copy input field value (type=password)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to copy the value of input field [type=password]?

This is my scenario ,I need to copy the value of password field and paste them in confirm password field in my signup page.

```
Password: <input type="password" name="pwd">
Confirm Password: <input type="password" name="Confirmpwd">
```

Actually,my question is how to copy the value in input field.(Using:ctrl+c or mouse right click copy option)

Comment: A few things: 1. Have you tried actually getting the value from the pwd field? You should be able to do this without any problems. 2. Is the whole point of the confirm password field not for the user to type the password in twice to check they didn't mistype one of the times?

Comment: Thank you.I agree that its not good to so.Shall ignore this.

Comment: Yeah, I think you misunderstand the actual purpose of what `Confirm Password` is for. It is a security feature to not copy/paste from `type=password`, but this really is a trivial task for jquery

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5896287/jquery-passing-value-from-one-input-to-another

Answer (score 0):

```
   // get the 2 elements
    var p1 = document.querySelector('input[name="pwd"]');

    var p2 = document.querySelector('input[name="Confirmpwd"]');

      // assign onchnage handler
       p1.onchange = function(){
       //get p1 value
        var val = this.value;
       // assign val to p2
        p2.value = val;
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

The Copy/Past should not be happen in the password field type for security reasons, the logic is to confirm that you enter the password two times correctly without copy and past it again!

Any way you may copy the value using the following code:

```
var input = document.getElementById('pwd');
var password = input.value;
text.value=password ;
```

I strongly advice you to not do this, and let the user to insert the password and confirm it again.

Answer (score 0):

```
// GET THE VALUE
var pw = $('input[name=pwd]').val();
// SET IT IN THE OTHER INPUT
$('input[name=Confirmpwd]').val( pw );
```

The cuestion here is, ¿Why? , that's not a "confirmation", just a copy/paste.