# How to transfer values from between input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Before anyone marks this as a duplicate, I have looked at many sites and am currently using this one - [jQuery - passing value from one input to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5896287/jquery-passing-value-from-one-input-to-another) for guidance, yet no result... I am trying to pass a value from one input in one form to another input in a 'table'. I have put it in a table because of a very weird reason - it does not display a `Sparql` value when in a form only displays in a table so the `input` was placed in a table. My code is below:

**Form**

```
<form  onclick="txtFullName.value = txtFirstName.value +'_'+ txtLastName.value">
    First name : <input type="text" name="txtFirstName" value="@ViewBag.FirstName"/> <br><br>
    Last name : <input type="text" name="txtLastName" value="@ViewBag.LastName" /> <br><br>
    Full name : <input type="text" id="txtFullName" name="txtFullName"> <br><br />
    <input id="submit12" type="button" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**Table**

```
 <table id="results">
       <Full name: 
        <br>
        <input id="userInput" type="text" name="fullname" ${userJson.userId == ''?'': 'disabled'} value="@ViewBag.DisplayName">
        <br>
        <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </table>
```

**JQUERY**

```
  $('#submit12').on('click', function (e) { //Form submit 
        $('#userInput').change(function () {
            $('txtFullName').val($(this).val());
        });
    });
```

I am trying to display the `txtFullName` into `userInput` input when pressing submit but right now only the `txtFullName' is displayed when pressing submit. Also the submit is the submit button in the FORM.

Anymore info needed let me know:)

Comment: You can't have an `input type=submit` outside of a form. Also, why use JQuery here?

Comment: @ScottMarcus because I was following the link posted.

Comment: $('txtFullName') - wrong selector.

Comment: Why not just use `$('#userInput').val($('#txtFullName').val());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the `onclick` to `action` on the form if you are trying to use submit button. The other way is to use input type button instead of submit:

So:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

     $('#submit12').on('click', function (e) { 
       console.log('test');
        $("#txtFullName").val($("#txtFirstName").val() + '_' + $("#txtLastName").val());        
    });
  
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    First name : <input type="text" id="txtFirstName" value="First"/> <br><br>
    Last name : <input type="text" id="txtLastName" value="Last" /> <br><br>
    Full name : <input type="text" id="txtFullName" name="txtFullName"> <br><br />
    <input id="submit12" type="button" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display txtFullName into userInput, simply do something like this:

```
$('#submit12').on('click', function (e) { //Form submit 
        $('#userInput').val($('#txtFullName').val());
});
```

And why do you need change function there , if yo need changes when click submit.

Answer (score 1):

Edit your JQuery like this:

```
$('#submit12').on('click', function (e) { //Form submit 
    $('#userInput').change(function () {
        $('#txtFullName').val($(this).val());
    });
});
$('#submit').on('click', function () { //Form submit         
    $('#userInput').val($('#txtFullName').val());
});
```

I don't clearly understand why you do it but It can fix your code.

Answer (score 0):

It is not entirely clear what the two buttons do, but the operation itself is really very simple. See comments inline for explanations:

```js
// Wait until the DOM is loaded and all elements are avaialble
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){

  // Get references to the DOM elements you'll need
  var theForm = document.getElementById("frmTest");
  var txtFirstName = document.getElementById("txtFirstName");
  var txtLasttName = document.getElementById("txtLastName");
  var txtFulltName = document.getElementById("txtFullName"); 
  var txtUserInput = document.getElementById("txtUserInput");   
  
  var btn1 = document.getElementById("btnSubmit1");
  var btn2 = document.getElementById("btnSubmit2");  
  
  // Function to join names together
  function combine(){
    txtFullName.value = txtFirstName.value + '_' + txtLastName.value;
  }
  
  // Set event handlers
  
  frmTest.addEventListener("click", combine);  
  btn1.addEventListener("click", combine);
     
});
```

```html
<!-- Keep you JavaScript out of your HTML -->
<form  id="frmTest">
    First name : <input type="text" id="txtFirstName" name="txtFirstName" value="@ViewBag.FirstName"> 
    <br><br>
    Last name : <input type="text" id="txtLastName" name="txtLastName" value="@ViewBag.LastName" > 
    <br><br>
    Full name : <input type="text" id="txtFullName" name="txtFullName"> <br><br />
    <input id="btnSubmit1" type="button" value="Combine Names">



 <table id="results">
       <Full name: 
        <br>
        <input id="txtUserInput" type="text" name="fullname" ${userJson.userId == ''?'': 'disabled'} value="@ViewBag.DisplayName">
        <br>
        <input id="btnSubmit2" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </table>
  
</form>
```